# Query to return available hotel rooms 3 days earlier or later than a specified range

Tags: mysql

I want to return available rooms in hotel reservation system. the query should return result 3 days earlier or later than specified date range.

DB Structure:

Room Table (RoomID, RoomType, BedsNo, ViewAvailable...)
Reservation Table (ReservationID, RoomID, CheckinDate, CheckoutDate...)

I'm using the below query to return available rooms within specified date range: DateFrom & DateTo. However, how to return results 3 days earlier or later than date range DateFrom & DateTo.

```
select * from room 
where room.roomId not in
(select reservation.roomId from reservation where 
  (reservation.check_in_date <= `FromDate` AND reservation.check_out_date >= `ToDate`) 
           OR (reservation.check_in_date < `FromDate` AND reservation.check_out_date >= `ToDate`) 
           OR (`FromDate` <= reservation.check_in_date AND `ToDate` >= reservation.check_out_date))
```

Comment: Have you tried to substract/add 3 days to your date?

Answer (score 0):

can't you just add 3 days to both `FromDate` and `ToDate` via something like

```
[...]
where reservation.check_in_data <= date_sub(FromDate, interval 3 day) 
and reservation.check_out_date >= date_add(ToDate, interval 3 day)
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

use INTERVAL

```
select * from room 
where room.roomId not in
(select reservation.roomId from reservation where 
  (reservation.check_in_date <= `FromDate` - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND reservation.check_out_date >= `ToDate` + INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
           OR (reservation.check_in_date < `FromDate` - INTERVAL 3 DAY AND reservation.check_out_date >= `ToDate` + INTERVAL 3 DAY) 
           OR (`FromDate` - INTERVAL 3 DAY <= reservation.check_in_date AND `ToDate` + INTERVAL 3 DAY >= reservation.check_out_date))
```